# Bootstrap.min.css.map missing

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, collectstatic

I cannot figure it out, how to make the server read bootstrap.min.css.map file.

Which of the way below would finally make it work?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
     {% block script %}{% endblock script %}
<script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
```

[image]

[image]